# When configuring a custom web user role in CommCare, can I restrict data access by location/organization?

Tags: commcare

I am configuring a custom web-user role in CommCare and I would like to restrict this web user's access to data by their location/organization designation in the organization structure. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the web-user's access to data outside of their designated location/organization by deselecting the check box next to "Allow role to access data from all locations."